# How to express elemental operations in matrix form?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, vector, vector-calculus

I ran the following code:

```
X = Array[x, {5, 4}];
W = Array[w, {4, 3}];
Y = Array[y, {5, 3}];
D[Norm[X.W-Y, "Frobenius"]^2, {W}]//MatrixForm
```

However, mma returns a very complex form:

```
({
  {2 Abs[
      w[1, 1] x[1, 1] + w[2, 1] x[1, 2] + w[3, 1] x[1, 3] + 
       w[4, 1] x[1, 4] - y[1, 1]] x[1, 1] Derivative[1][Abs][
      w[1, 1] x[1, 1] + w[2, 1] x[1, 2] + w[3, 1] x[1, 3] + 
       w[4, 1] x[1, 4] - y[1, 1]] + 
    2 Abs[
      w[1, 1] x[2, 1] + w[2, 1] x[2, 2] + w[3, 1] x[2, 3] + 
       w[4, 1] x[2, 4] - y[2, 1]] x[2, 1] Derivative[1][Abs][
      w[1, 1] x[2, 1] + w[2, 1] x[2, 2] + w[3, 1] x[2, 3] + 
       w[4, 1] x[2, 4] - y[2, 1]] + ...
```

How can I express such elemental operations in the form of matrix operations?

Comment: By default all variables are assumed to be complex. And for complex numbers the derivative of Abs is not defined. That is why you have "Abs'[...]" in the answer.

Comment: *Mathematica* is not yet able to do fully symbolic matrix calculus without having to write out explicit entries. In the meantime, have you already seen [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/pubs/3274-full.html)?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for sharing the Matrix Cookbook. I'd never come across it, and it looks like a great resource!